# HttpClient not sending the request to Web Api async get method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I haven't used Web Api in a while and I am stuck with something that should be very simple.

I have an asynchronous get method in a Web Api controller:

```
public class SomeController : ApiController  
{  
   [HttpGet]  
   public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyMethodAsync(Guid id)  
   {  
      //... doing something.
   }  
}
```

On my client application I am trying to call it like so:

```
using(var client = new HttpClient())
{
   var result = client.GetAsync($"{url}/Some/MyMethodAsync/{Guid.NewGuid()}"); 
   //I have tried making the above call with and without await
   //since I saw in some other post that it is not needed.

   //.... doing something else.

   //This POST method does stop in the beak point I set inside of it.
   var result2 = client.PostAsync($"{url}/Some/MyPostAsync", someContent);
}
```

The problem that I have is that it seems that the request is not even being sent to the Web Api since the break point that I am setting on MyMethodAsync has the warning that the symbols are not being loaded.

What really confuses me is that the next call is to a POST method on the same controller that when I call it the symbols load and its breakpoint gets hit.

Like I said, I am comming back to Web Api after a really long time and quite a few things are fuzzy in my mind. I only have the default route so, I do not know if I have to add more specific routes and if so, how to specify them.

As a side note I have two other GET methods that also have a Guid parameter. I have tried calling those with the same result.

Thank you for your help.

**UPDATE**: **To make matters more confusing. If I run the application but instead of using the client I open a browser and enter the url exactly as the client would do it, the break point in the action gets hit. Right after that I try using the client and then it won't.**

Comment: Did you try [HttpGet(“MyMethodAsync/{id}")]

Comment: @JoeB - I think that is the attribute for Asp .Net MVC because when I try to do that it won't compile telling me that the attribute's constructor has no parameters.

Comment: If you have 2 projects same time(one for api, and other for presentation layer), please set different ports, and start 2 projects together.

Comment: Try `client.GetAsync($"{url}/Some/MyMethodAsync?id={Guid.NewGuid()}")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. Open App_Start / WebApiConfig.cs

[image]

### 2. Add New Route

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "NewRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

#### 2.1. FULL Code

[image]

### 3. USE Action Name Attribute  [ActionName("MyMethod1")]

```
    [ActionName("MyMethod1")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult MyMethod1(Guid id)
    {
        return Ok<string>($" ok MyMethod1 and id= {id}");

    }
```

### 4. Same for  MyMethod2

```
    [ActionName("MyMethod2")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult MyMethod2(Guid id)
    {
        return Ok<string>($" ok MyMethod2 and id= {id}");

    }
```

### Extra Note : For the symbols are not being delete  error in  visual studio

- close visual studio
- Delete WebApplication1\bin
- Delete WebApplication1\obj
- Open visual studio
- build the solution
  [image]

Comment: @SergioRomero do yo still need help ?